# What does the |= operator do in python?

Tags: python, operators

As seen in the [following recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/409002/), the `|=` operator is used. I've never seen it before, and it's not documented. What does it mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the particular recipe you're asking about:

```
startupinfo.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
```

`dwFlags` is a bitmask, that is, it stores a number of flags in a single integer value by turning on the appropriate bits in the integer. In this case, `STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW` has a value of `1`, which means that this flag is set if the least significant bit in the `dwFlags` integer is `1`, and is not set if the LSB is `0`.

What the `|=` operator does in this case is to take the left operand and change it so the `1` bits in the left operand are set in it, and the rest of the bits are left alone.

For example, if it has some flags set such that it's binary representation before was, say, `00101000`, it will be set to `00101001`, adding `subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW` to the flags that are set without affecting the other flags that were set before the operation.

Answer (score 7):

It's an in-place `|`. `a |= b` is *mostly* equivalent to `a = a | b`.

Comment: And what does the `|` operator means? I didn't find it in the documentation as well.

Comment: With numbers it's [bitwise or](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations).

Comment: For fun, try `False |= True; False`

Answer (score 4):

`|=` is a so called [augmented assignment statement](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#augmented-assignment-statements). Its purpose is to do an in-place or operation, just as [the normal `|` operation](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations).

There are, however, some sublte differences, as a different method of the object is called: for `|`, it is [`__or__()`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__or__) or [`__ror__()`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__ror__), for `|=`, it is [`__ior__()`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__ior__).

Answer (score 1):

`a |= b`  means the same as `a = a | b`.

Comment: cares to give a reason for down voting?

Comment: Probably the one has gone already. But maybe it was because of the absolute claim "the same as" - it is not the same in all circumstances. Nevertheless, I would not have downvoted (but not up as well).

Comment: E.g., in the case of sets, where `|` is the union of 2 sets, both statements mean sth. else: `a |= b` modifies the object referred by `a`, while `a = a | b` creates a new object and lets `a` refer it.